# Error 424-no such object when doing an Excel autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that contains pricing information.  I'm trying to remove any rows that have a price that does not end in .99.  The column the pricing is in is column J.  So my code section for this is the following:

```
Columns("J:J").NumberFormat = "@"
With Columns("J")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*.99", VisibleDropDown:=False
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter
End With
```

I thought converting the cells to text format from numeric would allow me to use the <> evaluation, but it doesn't like that, keeps throwing a 424 object not found error and pointing to the first of the two consecutive .AutoFilter lines in the code.

Comment: If you remove the two additional .AutoFilter lines from your code it should work - or at least does for me.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any particular purpose for the 2 additional .AutoFilter lines?  I have a long series of these blocks of code for various rows I am removing based on the matching of a particular string.  All of them work fine but this one did not.  Just wondering if I can remove them from all of my blocks if they serve no purpose.

Comment: Still not working, when removing those 2 lines the macro removes all rows, even those that do not match the criteria.

Comment: Okay I see what's happening.  The problem is that you have to have the column formatted as text before you enter values into the cells.  Once you do that the autofilter as is will work.  But otherwise I'm not sure how to fix this - ie force excel to turn the cells to text before the autofilter is run.  The only thing I can suggest is to maybe use something else like match or a regular expression instead.

Comment: I do format the cells as text with the first line of code:Columns("J:J").NumberFormat = "@"  How were you able to get to work?

Comment: Sorry, this line:

Comment: I know the numberformat command should be converting to it text but for some reason the autofilter command isn't recognizing the change.  After you run it (and all the lines are deleted) the column will be formatted as text.  Now if you enter data in that column and run it again it'll work.  I don't know how to correct for this behavior.